# Flutter Bluestacks issue

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

My application looks different from what i installed in BlueStacks and Android Emulator, for example:
[image]

Mostly difference in size and padding. Tried setting the width for the container like MediaQuery.of(context).size.width but it doesn't work. Tried expanded, it refuses to work with carousel. It just stops displaying it. Part of my code with carousel:

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: < Widget > [
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                            ),
                            child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                    hintText: 'Найти услугу...',
                                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Column(
                            children: [
                                Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                                    child: TabBar(
                                        controller: _tabController,
                                        labelColor: Colors.white,
                                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // Creates border
                                            color: const Color(0xFF62A6E9)),
                                        tabs: [
                                            Tab(icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/trending.svg',
                                                color: _tabController.index == 0 ?
                                                Colors.white :
                                                Color(0xFF71768D),
                                                width: 25,
                                                height: 25
                                            ), text: "Популярное"),
                                            Tab(icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/new.svg',
                                                color: _tabController.index == 1 ?
                                                Colors.white :
                                                Color(0xFF71768D),
                                                width: 25,
                                                height: 25
                                            ), text: "Новые"),
                                            Tab(icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/comingsoon.svg',
                                                color: _tabController.index == 2 ?
                                                Colors.white :
                                                Color(0xFF71768D),
                                                width: 25,
                                                height: 25
                                            ), text: "Ожидаемые"),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 30),
                                SizedBox(
                                    height: 230.0,
                                    child: TabBarView(
                                        controller: _tabController,
                                        children: [
                                            Stack(
                                                children: < Widget > [
                                                    CarouselSlider(
                                                        options: CarouselOptions(
                                                            autoPlay: false,
                                                            aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                                            viewportFraction: 0.6,
                                                            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                                                setState(() {
                                                                    _current = index;
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        ),
                                                        items: imageSliders,
                                                    ),
                                                    Positioned(
                                                        bottom: 0.0,
                                                        right: 0.0,
                                                        left: 0.0,
                                                        child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                            children: imgList.map((url) {
                                                                int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
                                                                return Container(
                                                                    width: 8.0,
                                                                    height: 8.0,
                                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                                        color: _current == index ?
                                                                        const Color(0xFF62A6E9): const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                                                    ),
                                                                );
                                                            }).toList(),
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                ]
                                            ),
                                            Stack(
                                                children: < Widget > [
                                                    CarouselSlider(
                                                        options: CarouselOptions(
                                                            autoPlay: false,
                                                            aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                                            viewportFraction: 0.6,
                                                            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                                                setState(() {
                                                                    _current2 = index;
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        ),
                                                        items: imageSliders,
                                                    ),
                                                    Positioned(
                                                        bottom: 0.0,
                                                        right: 0.0,
                                                        left: 0.0,
                                                        child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                            children: imgList.map((url) {
                                                                int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
                                                                return Container(
                                                                    width: 8.0,
                                                                    height: 8.0,
                                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                                        color: _current2 == index ?
                                                                        const Color(0xFF62A6E9): const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                                                    ),
                                                                );
                                                            }).toList(),
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                ]
                                            ),
                                            Stack(
                                                children: < Widget > [
                                                    CarouselSlider(
                                                        options: CarouselOptions(
                                                            autoPlay: false,
                                                            aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                                            viewportFraction: 0.6,
                                                            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                                                setState(() {
                                                                    _current3 = index;
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        ),
                                                        items: imageSliders,
                                                    ),
                                                    Positioned(
                                                        bottom: 0.0,
                                                        right: 0.0,
                                                        left: 0.0,
                                                        child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                            children: imgList.map((url) {
                                                                int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
                                                                return Container(
                                                                    width: 8.0,
                                                                    height: 8.0,
                                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                                        color: _current3 == index ?
                                                                        const Color(0xFF62A6E9): const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                                                    ),
                                                                );
                                                            }).toList(),
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                ]
                                            ),
                                        ]
                                    ),
                                )
                            ],
                        ),
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Why is this happening? In the screenshot, carousel in Bluestask is not full width